# Where is the right way that should you put your resources (i.e Images and Sound files) when trying to create a JAR file?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jar, resources, embedded-resource

I am using Intellij IDEA and whenever I build a JAR artifact it places itself on the productions folder. When I try to run the JAR file some custom defined functions (i.e. setting Icons on Components and adding sounds) are missing, while running it on the Intellij's IDEA is functioning correctly. I know that it involves using getResourceAsStream method but is there some sort of right way to place external resources?

Additional questions I may add, where is the correct destination for placing the META-INF folder? Should I make a resource folder for all my external files?

Answer (score 1):

This is for Eclipse users, I believe the same thing can be accomplished in other IDE's relatively easily.

- Create a resources folder
- Put your non-code files in it
- Use as "Source Folder"

[image]

After creating the JAR, the contents of "resources" will be packed in the JAR.